# Problems rendering a game using libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to represent some images using libgdx. For that i have rectangles and textures variables. The problem is that when i let the code run this way it paints the images only 1 time, clearing it right after. I want the images to stay if i painted them.

```
 @Override
        public void render () {
            int x,y;
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            batch.begin();
            if(matrixBuilt!=true){
            for(x=0;x<matrix.length;x++){
                for(y=0;y<matrix.length;y++){
                    System.out.println(matrix[x][y]);
                    switch(matrix[x][y]){
                    case 1: batch.draw(numberOne, numberOneR.x, numberOneR.y);
                    break;
                    case 2: batch.draw(numberTwo, numberTwoR.x, numberTwoR.y);
                    break;
                    case 3: batch.draw(numberThree, numberThreeR.x, numberThreeR.y);
                    break;
                    case 4: batch.draw(numberFour, numberFourR.x, numberFourR.y);
                    break;
                    case 5: batch.draw(numberFive, numberFiveR.x, numberFiveR.y);
                    break;
                    case 6: batch.draw(numberSix, numberSixR.x, numberSixR.y);
                    break;
                    case 7: batch.draw(numberSeven, numberSevenR.x, numberSevenR.y);
                    break;
                    case 8: batch.draw(numberEight, numberEightR.x, numberEightR.y);
                    break;
                    case 9: batch.draw(numberNine, numberNineR.x, numberNineR.y);
                    break;
                    case 10: batch.draw(emptySquare, emptySquareR.x, emptySquareR.y);
                    break;
                    }   
                }
            }
            matrixBuilt=true;
            }


            batch.end();
        }
```

Altough if i do a `batch.draw(emptySquare, emptySquareR.x, emptySquareR.y);` before batch.end(); it is ok but i dont want that.... it would make the code be very extense... any clues? thanks.

EDIT:

So i put these on create method :

```
Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
```

and the rendering is only happening once IF i don't pass through the screen with my mouse, because if I do that it will repaint, and i dont want that to happen, I want the images to be static, here's my code at this momment :

```
 public void render () {

    int x,y,squareCounter=0;

    batch.begin();
    for(x=0;x<matrix.length;x++){
        for(y=0;y<matrix.length;y++){
            System.out.println(matrix[x][y]);
            switch(matrix[x][y]){
            case 1: 
                if(squareCounter==9) {squareCounter=0;startingX=125;startingY-=40;numberOneR.x=startingX;numberOneR.y=startingY; }
                batch.draw(numberOne, numberOneR.x, numberOneR.y);
                squareCounter++;
                startingX+=40;
                numberOneR.x=startingX;
            break;
            case 2:
                if(squareCounter==9) {squareCounter=0;startingX=125;startingY-=40;numberTwoR.x=startingX;numberTwoR.y=startingY; }
                batch.draw(numberTwo, numberTwoR.x, numberTwoR.y);
                squareCounter++;
                startingX+=40;
                numberTwoR.x=startingX;
            break;
            case 3: 
                if(squareCounter==9) {squareCounter=0;startingX=125;startingY-=40;numberThreeR.x=startingX;numberThreeR.y=startingY; }
                batch.draw(numberThree, numberThreeR.x, numberThreeR.y);
                squareCounter++;
                startingX+=40;
                numberThreeR.x=startingX;
            break;
            case 4: 
                if(squareCounter==9) {squareCounter=0;startingX=125;startingY-=40;numberFourR.x=startingX;numberFourR.y=startingY; }
                batch.draw(numberFour, numberFourR.x, numberFourR.y);
                squareCounter++;
                startingX+=40;
                numberFourR.x=startingX;
            break;
            case 5: 
                if(squareCounter==9) {squareCounter=0;startingX=125;startingY-=40;numberFiveR.x=startingX;numberFiveR.y=startingY; }
                batch.draw(numberFive, numberFiveR.x, numberFiveR.y);
                squareCounter++;
                startingX+=40;
                numberFiveR.x=startingX;
            break;
            case 6: 
                if(squareCounter==9) {squareCounter=0;startingX=125;startingY-=40;numberSixR.x=startingX;numberSixR.y=startingY; }
                batch.draw(numberSix, numberSixR.x, numberSixR.y);
                squareCounter++;
                startingX+=40;
                numberSixR.x=startingX;
            break;
            case 7: 
                if(squareCounter==9) {squareCounter=0;startingX=125;startingY-=40;numberSevenR.x=startingX;numberSevenR.y=startingY; }
                batch.draw(numberSeven, numberSevenR.x, numberSevenR.y);
                squareCounter++;
                startingX+=40;
                numberSevenR.x=startingX;
            break;
            case 8: 
                if(squareCounter==9) {squareCounter=0;startingX=125;startingY-=40;numberEightR.x=startingX;numberEightR.y=startingY; }
                batch.draw(numberEight, numberEightR.x, numberEightR.y);
                squareCounter++;
                startingX+=40;
                numberEightR.x=startingX;
            break;
            case 9: 
                if(squareCounter==9) {squareCounter=0;startingX=125;startingY-=40;numberNineR.x=startingX;numberNineR.y=startingY; }
                batch.draw(numberNine, numberNineR.x, numberNineR.y);
                squareCounter++;
                startingX+=40;
                numberNineR.x=startingX;
            break;
            case 10: 
                if(squareCounter==9) {squareCounter=0;startingX=125;startingY-=40;emptySquareR.x=startingX;emptySquareR.y=startingY; }
                batch.draw(emptySquare, emptySquareR.x, emptySquareR.y);
                squareCounter++;
                startingX+=40;
                emptySquareR.x=startingX;
            break;
            }   
        }
    }
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: That is how OpenGL works. You always clear and redraw the entire scene with each call to `render()`, so all you need to do is remove your `if(matrixBuilt!=true)` condition. If your matrix is enormous (several hundred elements) and this is going to actually cause a performance issue, you can draw this stuff onto a FrameBuffer one time, and then draw the single `frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture()` to the screen instead.

Comment: By the way, I see a potential bug... shouldn't it be `for(y=0;y<matrix[x].length;y++){` instead of what you have?

Comment: no, i want to go through all the matrix possibilities (im trying to do sudoku)

Comment: I was assuming a non-square 2D matrix, but since it will be 9x9, it doesn't matter. Regarding your intial question: you can also use non-continuous rendering to save battery, since this is only a Sudoku game: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-&-non-continuous-rendering

Comment: now a new problem occured, rendered was in fact called once but if I let my mouse roam over the screen it will blink the images for every move i make with the mouse, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that inside your `render` method, you call:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Which first sets the `ClearColor` and then clears the screen with it e.g. sets the whole screen to this color.
Possible solutions would be:

1. Remove the 2 calls, this would stop the clearing. But that also means, that everything you draw stays on screen, until you call those methods again.
2. Draw all (visible) things every frame, like most games do it. In your case it should be enough to remove the `if(!matrixBuilt)` condition.
3. Draw those things to a `FrameBuffer` once and then use this `FrameBuffer` to draw the things to the screen, as @Tenfour04 mentioned.
4. Use non-continuous rendering, as @Tenfour04 mentioned, which would stop the gameloop from calling the `render()` method all the times. Instead you then would need to call `Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();` to get the `render()` called.

I guess, the last solution would be the best in this case, as the shown content is more or less static and non-continuous rendering can save battery.
You could call the `Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();` on events like user-inputs and something similar.
For other games, where more things are moving on screen (like platformers and so on), the second method is the best in most cases.

Comment: how do I use non-continuous rendering ?

Comment: The link @Tenfour04 posted (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-&-non-continuous-rendering) should help. Basicly you need to disable continuous rendering by calling `Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);` and then call `Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();` whenever you want your `render()` to be called.

Comment: now a new problem occured, rendered was in fact called once but if I let my mouse roam over the screen it will blink the images for every move i make with the mouse, any ideas?

Comment: @pmpc could you please update the question with the new code? Just add an **EDIT** at the end and add the new code, so that the actual question does not get lost.

Comment: maybe I should do an array that saves the images of the same number?

Comment: If you want the image to be static, save it to a `FrameBuffer` once and the `draw` that `FrameBuffer` every time you call `render()`. If you are using non-continuous rendering, `render()` gets called, on user input to. Thats why it calls `render()` when you move the mouse. I did not exactly understand, why you want to render those things only once. Can you please explain that?

Comment: i dont know if im explaining well, i want to show a matrix not filled ! and then i want the user to be able to pick a empty square and choose a number to put in there

Comment: Yea i understood that, but the drawing of the matrix is ot verry complicated or ressource heavy, so you can do this every `render()`, without any problems. So you could use the non-continuous rendering like you do it now, but draw the matrix EVERY time `render()` is called. After that you can draw the numbers, which will then be on top of the matrix.

Comment: one more question: as you know there will be 9 numbers which will be the same, and everytime i set their "number.x = something" and "number.y = something" is that going to forget the last Rectangle of the last number?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with that... If you say `number.x=something`, the old value of `number.x` will be lost. If you mean, if the other numbers you set will be lost, that depends on your code. I guess the easiest way would be to store the numbers in a `int[][] numbers` which has a size of 9*9. The first number would be at `numbers[0][0]`, the last at `numbers[8][8]`. If you set a new number to a cell of the matrix, you need to set the right number in the `numbers[][]` at the right position. Then you need to `draw` all the numbers inside the `numbers[][]`

Comment: that's not what i mean't im sorry, i'll try again: Imagine that you have a Rectangle called numberOne -> private Rectangle numberOne;
but in my whole game i will have 9 numberOne's ... so imagine that i put the first numberOne in number.x=50 and number.y=50 (batch.draw(numberOneTexture, number.x=50, number.y=50)), and the second numberOne in number.x=100 and number.y=100(batch.draw(numberOneTexture, number.x=100, number.y=100)), what i want to know is if the first rectangle will be lost? because i want all rectangles to be preservated for the future interface with the user

Comment: Well, if you change the `x`, `y`, `width` or `height` of the `Rectangle`, it's previous values will be lost. But i don't see any use of `Rectangle` in your case. For user interaction like touch and so on, i would use `Scene2D`, so the cells of your matrix could be `Actor`s (or subclasses).

Comment: can you help me here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986403/how-to-select-and-deselect-a-rectangle-texture-properly-on-click